# How to change jpanels in one jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

i wanna make a jframe that the jpanel in it genna get info about users and after that when they click the button , i want to change the jpanel to access the main page, but i can't find any way to change the panel without changing jframe?could you please help me!

Comment: 1) **Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).** 2) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle. 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for working examples. The tutorial has section of all Swing basics.